# How stop if statement not loop in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, break

I have an issue that: if 'while' started and first condition 'false' it kept going to 'else' even the 'if' became 'true', I need to stay in the loop but stop if statement to start looping all if statements, I hope I explained the question in a clear way, I tried break(), pass() and continue() and all of them stop the loop.

```py
CurrentTime = datetime.now().time()

Actual_Time = CurrentTime.strftime("%H:%M")
Static_Time = '15:54'
while True:
    print('Teeest Looop')
    if (Actual_Time == Static_Time) :
        print('Teeest')
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\hana\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
        time.sleep(20)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='hana']").click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]'))).send_keys('test sending')
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='_2Ujuu']"))).click()
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.close()       
    elif (Actual_Time != Static_Time) :
        print('Not lucky time')
```

Comment: Are you sure of the indentation? It looks like you haven't placed an indentation inside your while loop.

Comment: yes I'm sure but when I copied the code here it's changed

Comment: @Hana I don't see a for loop, or any of `break`, `continue`, `pass`. Where are you trying to do that? What are you trying to do, and what's happening?

Comment: Also the `elif` can just be `else`. You never change `Actual_Time` or `Static_Time`, so why would they be different?

Comment: oh sorry I typed for instead of while I update the question, the break, continue, pass I tried it and eliminating it here so ensure not confusing who have a solution, thank you

Comment: I tried else and the same issue so I tried elif and also the same issue

Comment: If you don't show us what you're trying to break out of, we can' help. I think the main issue with this loop, is that `Actual_Time` and `Static_Time` never change, so you will always get the same side of the if statement.

Comment: **continue** works well, i guess you tried as `continue()` use just `continue`

Comment: @blueteeth please recheck the question, I compared the current time with the time I entered

Comment: thank you @AliAref I add continue  for both 'if' and 'else' and the same issue

Comment: @Hana, still don't really understand what the problem is, but I can guess. You set the times outside the while loop. Then you enter the loop, unless the time is actually 15:54, you always get the else condition executing, over and over again. If you want it to stop after one iteration, either don't put it in a while loop, or add a `break`. If you want something different to happen, you need to set `Actual_Time` inside the while loop.

Comment: Thank you @blueteeth its work now I add second to the time, please add your answer as an answer to make it acceptable, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting values that never change outside the `while` loop, and then you never update them inside the loop, so the `if`-condition based on them never evaluates to anything different.

I think you want something like

```py
from datetime import datetime

do_something_time = "15:54"

while True:
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
    if current_time == do_something_time:
        print("Doing something")  # this only prints at 15:54
    elif current_time == "00:00":
        break  # this exits the while loop at midnight
    else:
        print("Not this time!")
```